# Issue with jQuery toggle() Method

Tags: jquery

Can you please  take a look at following link and let me know why the toggle() is not working in the code?

http://jsfiddle.net/GISMan/ZNkKZ/1/

here is the code as well,

```
function fluctuate(bar) {
var hgt = Math.random() * 10;
hgt += 1;
var t = hgt * 30;
bar.animate({
    height: hgt
}, t, function() {
    fluctuate($(this));
});
}
$(".bar").each(function(i) {
fluctuate($(this));
});

$("button").toggle(function(){
$(".bar").stop();},
function(){
$(".bar").fluctuate();}
);
```

​
Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNkKZ/2/)** — *Fixed.*

Change:

```
$(".bar").fluctuate();
```

to:

```
fluctuate($(".bar"));
```

Comment: Thanks again Coby, it is late accept because I didn't' have enough credit to accept sooner