# Website background music with custom start and pause button

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Can any one let me know how I can add a background to a website using jPlayer and jQuery without having player on the screen? Please find an example here:

http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/picturesque/#/fashion/3

I am also thinking to have a custom button like this [image] to stop and start the music (using toggle method)

Comment: You have yet to **"accept"** my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328733 - How to accept an answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Sorry Coby i tried to accept it last time but system didn't let me to go through.